# Why does the mountpoint of my root filesystem change?

Tags: filesystems, btrfs, docker

When I look at the output of `lsblk` it will usually show:

```
lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0  1023M  0 part /boot
└─sda2   8:2    0 297.1G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

with `/` being the mountpoint of my root filesystem. However, if I start `sudo systemctl start docker` I get the following output:

```
lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0  1023M  0 part /boot
└─sda2   8:2    0 297.1G  0 part /var/lib/docker/btrfs
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

and now the mountpoint of my root filesystem has according to `lsblk` changed to `/var/lib/docker/btrfs`. This raises three questions for me:

1. Is this true?
2. Is this in order or should this not be the case?
3. Why?

Comment: 1. yes, 2. yes, 3. because that is [docker's primary function](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/docker-explained-how-to-containerize-and-use-nginx-as-a-proxy)

Comment: As far as I can see the [text](http://goo.gl/o5MpN2) you linked does not explain how and why docker changes the mountpoint of the filesystem. It is also ab bit dated given what has changed in the last time in how docker works. My own explanation is that docker uses the btrfs snapshot tool to store images and that it changes the mountpoint to the default place where it stores the snapshots/images; namely `/var/lib/docker/btrfs`. This can be verified by looking into the folder. I just wanted to make sure that I'm not totally off.

Comment: it's because it *docks* the container to */*. your explanation is right-on, though. they're one and the same. `docker` deals with container images - it's basically a `chroot`, but kernel implemented... or *(because `chroot` is kernel implemented)* a more *complete* `chroot`, maybe.

Comment: Cheers @mikeserv! I was really puzzled for a moment by the output of `lsblk`.

Comment: @mikeserv, as you were the first to answer my question/confirm my suspicion, do you want to post it as an answer so that I can accept it? (I hope this is ok @pqnet.)

Comment: No, though I appreciate the offer. You should feel free to do so if you feel there is anything to add though. If you do so, ping me in a comment there so I can look at it, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partition can be mounted in multiple paths, but the `lsblk` will only show one. In your case `/dev/sda2` contains a `btrfs` filesystem, which is mounted both as `/` and as `/var/lib/docker/btrfs`, probably with two different `subvolumes`. To see more details on how stuff are mounted around your system use `cat /proc/mounts`.

As for number 3, my guess is that docker uses btrfs subvolumes as storage for linux containers for running jailed daemons. This allows for easily creating snapshots of these containers.

Comment: Cheers @pqnet! Indeed, there are two `subvolumes` mounted at `/dev/sda2`; namely `/` and `/var/lib/docker/btrfs`.